# HTTP/2 issue with Jetty - invalid preface

Tags: java, curl, jetty, http2

I'm experimenting with HTTP/2. I found some examples in [this repo](https://github.com/grro/http2/tree/master/src/test/java/eu/redzoo/article/javaworld/http2). Here's the constructor (boilerplate code skipped):

```
public WebServer(String path, HttpServlet servlet, int port) {
    Server server = new Server(new QueuedThreadPool());
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/", ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(servlet), path);
    ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server, 1,1, new HTTP2ServerConnectionFactory(new HttpConfiguration()));
    connector.setPort(port);
    server.addConnector(connector);
}
```

Then I `start()` the server, run java http2 client from the mentioned above repo and it connects with no error. But then I try to do the same with curl:

```
# curl --http2 http://localhost:8080
invalid_preface
```

And the browser (Chrome) says:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/ net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE
```

What's whong with the server?

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with the server.

You have configured Jetty to listen to HTTP/2 only (no HTTP/1.1), and then you have asked `curl` and Chrome to make a HTTP/1.1 request, which Jetty replied with `invalid_preface` because it cannot understand it.

Bear in mind that browsers will only speak HTTP/2 over TLS (i.e. SSL), while `curl` is able to also speak clear-text HTTP/2.

[This example](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.5.v20170502/jetty-http2/http2-server/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/http2/server/HTTP2CServer.java) shows you how to setup a server that supports both clear-text HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2.

[This example](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.5.v20170502/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/Http2Server.java) shows you how to setup a server that supports both clear-text and TLS HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2.

See [here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http2.html) for how to use `curl` with HTTP/2.

Comment: Thank you for explanation of browser restrictions. Still, if I use `--http2` flag with curl it fails with the same message.

Comment: `curl` does not fail for me. Perhaps you have an old version of `curl`, or an old version of `openssl`, etc. You need to make sure your `curl` version works fine with HTTP/2, and if you still have errors, post the full server logs and client logs.